# Creating a Realm List<> to populate UITableView

Tags: swift, list, uitableview, realm

I have created a Realm which stores a list of strings of information about numerous user added Meals. Previous questions I have asked have led me to try to create a List<> to populate my UITableView for user interaction, rather than to pull from the Realm file directly.

Here is where I am seeking help. The `MealRecords` class shows in RealmStudio. The `mealRecordsList` shows in RealmStudio with nothing listed in the column below it.

When a new `MealRecord` is written to the Realm, the `MealRecords` class remains empty.

[image]

Looking for help to fill the `MealRecords` with a List of all of the 'MealRecord' entries to be able to use to populate a UITableView Controller.

**Creating the classes**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MealRecords: Object {
        let mealRecordList = List<MealRecord>()
}

class MealRecord : Object {
    @objc dynamic var mealName = ""
    @objc dynamic var mainIngredient = ""
    
    convenience init (mealName: String, mainIngredient: String) {
        self.init()
        self.mealName = mealName
        self.mainIngredient = mainIngredient
        
    }
}
```

**User data entry scene with segue to UITableView scene**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift



class homeVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainIngredientText: UITextField!
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveTapped", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mealNameText.delegate = self
        self.mainIngredientText.delegate = self

        let realm = try! Realm()
               print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "saveTapped" {
            let dest = segue.destination as! UITableViewController
            
            let realm = try! Realm()
            
            var newMeal = MealRecord()
            newMeal.mealName = mealNameText.text!
            newMeal.mainIngredient = mainIngredientText.text!
            
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(newMeal)
                
                print("Added \(newMeal.mealName) to Realm")
                print("The number of MealRecords in memory is",realm.objects(MealRecord.self).count)
                print("The following is the MealRecords:", realm.objects(MealRecords.self))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output in console after saving meal to realm**

```
Optional(file:///Users/MacUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E39E9725-4B83-49FE-81CB-8A7021DBDFD5/data/Containers/Data/Application/EE9C13A9-A4B3-4ED9-A2C6-0B2DC610E314/Documents/default.realm)
Added Chicken Tikka Masala to Realm
The number of MealRecords in memory is 5
The following is the MealRecords: Results<MealRecords> <0x7fb5a8d54890> (

)
```

I have scoured the internet for any information, but as a newbie still, a lot of the documentation and other examples I have seen need a little clarification on what and why is happening to enable me to transfer to my situation. Particularly information found in Realm's [List Class Reference](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html#/s:10RealmSwift4ListCACyxGycfc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear why you have two objects for this or why a List is being used. Maybe a simpler solution would be better. Here's some very abbreviated conceptual code:.

Note that a List is not needed; the realm Results object work perfectly well as a tableView dataSource

Start with your existing MealRecord object

```
class MealRecord : Object {
    @objc dynamic var mealName = ""
    @objc dynamic var mainIngredient = ""
    
    convenience init (mealName: String, mainIngredient: String) {
        self.init()
        self.mealName = mealName
        self.mainIngredient = mainIngredient 
    }
}
```

Let's create three meals

```
let breakfastObject = MealRecord(mealName: "my breakfast", mainIngredient: "eggs")
let lunchObject = MealRecord(mealName: "my lunch", mainIngredient: "lettuce")
let dinnerObject = MealRecord(mealName: "my dinner", mainIngredient: "steak")
```

then write them to realm

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try realm.write {
   realm.add(breakfastObject)
   realm.add(lunchObject)
   realm.add(dinnerObject)
}
```

then later we want to populate a tableView dataSource with our meal objects

```
class homeVC: UIViewController {
   var myTableViewDataSource: Results<MealRecord>? = nil

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myTableViewDataSource = realm.objects(MealRecord.self)
        tableView.reloadData()
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return self.myTableViewDataSource.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
      let myMeal = self.myTableViewDataSource[indexPath.row]
      //do something with the myMeal, populate cellView et
      return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jay! I tried the List approach as many forums recommended the List as Realms approach to Swifts Array's. I had to force unwrap myTableViewDataSource! at both the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt functions. A very detailed answer, most grateful.